# apache 2.4 ban a range of ips except for one included in range

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My site, like most eCommerce sites these day, is constantly being attacked by numerous hackers trying to glean information from the site. 
By using in house monitors, I have identified a large range of IP addresses that are being used by hackers and I have added these to my .htaccess file using the following format:-

```
<Files *>
  <RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require not ip 1.160.0.0/12
  </RequireAll>
</Files>
```

This is just an sample of the IP ranges that I am blocking(I have identified over 3,600 IP ranges in total).

As you can see, these IP ranges cover a large number of IP addresses, which is good as I do not want to list each individual IP address in the .htaccess file.

Unfortunately I have a customers whose IP address in within one of the banned ranges, for example 1.160.5.160 and I want to banned the IP range except for IP 1.160.5.160.

I have tried many combination of `require`, `require any`, `require all` and `require none` but I just cannot seem to get it to work.

So basically I want to allow all access unless the IP is in one of my ranges except if the IP is (in this example) 1.160.5.160

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

After much faffing about (research), I finally managed to find the answer my own question.
The answer lies in where you place the IP’s that you want to allow within the  structure or to be me precise without the  structure.
It seems that if you have already banned an IP range and want to allow an IP within the banned range, you must place this IP address after the closing 
 line.
Here is an example

```
<Files *>
<RequireAll>
Require not ip 2.222.109.0/24
</RequireAll>
#LIST OF IP EXCLUSIONS
Require ip 2.222.109.126
</Files>
```

Simple really.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_PageiEg9FypGeXAvw). It is designed for exactly this purpose and will take care of this at the firewall where such things should take place.

Alternatively consider adding the list of addresses you want to block to the firewall manually however you can configure fail2ban to do this too.

Comment: Not exactly the answer I was looking for as my server already runs auto blocking techniques.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the information gained from these techniques is what determines the address ranges you want to block more broadly speaking?

Comment: Basically yes. I have been monitoring all requests to the server fror a number of years now and based upon that analysis, I have banned a whole number of IP addresses. I have also integrated/banned known spamming IP ranges from another consultant who is basically monitoring the same information.

Comment: The ips that I have banned number in their thousands, so I basically convert these IPs into a single entry CIDR to save entries in my .htaccess file but as I mentioned before, some genuine customer IP addresses also get banned and it is these that I want to allow through but also continue with the banned IP ranges